# Offsetting horizontal line labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, linestring, offset

In QGIS 3.22.8 I have 100s of linear features on a map. I want to label them horizontally, but don't want the label sitting over the line. I can find the Horizontal placement setting, but no offset setting.

Currently, my labels look like this:

[image]

How can I shift these labels to the right so the text starts next to the line feature? I'm not keen to use workarounds, such as padding the label text with a load of white space before the text.

My label settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the Label Anchoring settings (in the middle of the Placement tab)?

Comment: If no better answer you can manually place each label (obviously this is only doable for a reasonable number of label)

Comment: @BERA label anchoring only sets where on the line the label will be (start middle or end). There's no offsetting there.

Comment: @J.R sure, but looking for a solution for 100s of features. Will clarify in OP

Answer (score 3):

Use a label placement based on Geometry Generator: create a (small) buffer around the lines and use placement <kbd>Outside Polygons</kbd>.

**How to do:**

In Placement settings, set the `Mode` to <kbd>Outside Polygons</kbd>, then check the box next to `Geoemtry Generator` and add this expression: `buffer($geometry, 0.6)` and below select <kbd>Polygon/MultiPolygon</kbd>. Change the size of `0.6` to fit your needs.

[image]